# reading from jdbc ResultSet is slow

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm reading data from a ResultSet and it seems to be slow (maybe, sadly, that's just the speed you can get).

I'm reading 568,365 rows with 5 columns. I've broken up the code and added timers to see where the most time is spend.

```
ResultSet.next() - about 65ms
ResultSet.wasNull() - about 150ms
ResultSet.getString/Double() - about 1000ms
```

So I'm looking to cut down the time off getting strings/doubles.

My connection creating:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=dbname", "user", "pass")
```

My statement creating:

```
conn.createStatement()
```

I tried playing with "setFetchSize" (1000, 10000, 500000) and "selectMethod=cursor/direct", but no luck.

I only what to loop through and retrieve the data, so if there are any other hits or setting I could tried to give JDBC...?

My code is (with the timers):

```
private List<Object[]> getResultRows(ResultSet queryResult) throws SQLException {
    List<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = queryResult.getMetaData();
    int colNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    int[] colTypes = new int[colNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
        colTypes[i] = rsmd.getColumnType(i + 1);
    }

    StopWatch next = new StopWatch();
    StopWatch read = new StopWatch();
    read.start();
    read.suspend();

    StopWatch isnull = new StopWatch();

    isnull.start();
    isnull.suspend();

    next.start();

    // Run on rows
    while (queryResult.next()) {

        next.suspend();

        Object[] rowValues = new Object[colNumber];

        // Run on columns
        for (int i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {

            read.resume();

            rowValues[i] = this.getValueByType(i + 1, colTypes[i], queryResult);

            read.suspend();
            isnull.resume();

            // if last value was null - set null
            if (queryResult.wasNull())
                rowValues[i] = null;

            isnull.suspend();
        }

        rows.add(rowValues);

        next.resume();
    }

    next.suspend();

    return rows;
}

private Object getValueByType(int columnIndex, int columnType, ResultSet queryResult) throws SQLException {
    switch (columnType) {
        case Types.CHAR:
        case Types.NCHAR:
        case Types.VARCHAR:
        case Types.NVARCHAR:
            return queryResult.getString(columnIndex);
        case Types.INTEGER:
            return queryResult.getInt(columnIndex);
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            return queryResult.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        case Types.DATE:
            return queryResult.getDate(columnIndex);
        default:
            return queryResult.getDouble(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is 1000 ms to read 5 columns of 568,365 rows slow in your opinion?

Comment: I would have guessed that the "next()" would be the slow part. isn't it going to the server to get a chunk of rows? why is reading the cells from the resultset slow? isn't it already in memory? (I've actually seen in other posts people complaining about the "next()" being slow, not the read).

Comment: Not necessarily; it depends a lot on the implementation of the driver, etc. First of all the fetch size makes it so that it is retrieved in chunks, and the network itself can be used as a buffer: the driver can request more rows ahead of time, and only read those back from the stream when it really needs them. Second, the decoding and conversion of raw bytes to the requested values can take significant time.

Comment: so are there thing i could try to reduce the time there? any hints for the jdbc or something?

Comment: As I said before, you first need to ask yourself if this is this really slow. Rounding up you spend maybe 1.3 seconds on 568,365 rows, that is 2.2 microseconds per row.